# AZURE Blobs .ListBlobs() extend the limit

Tags: c#, azure, blob

```
var allBlobls = container
  .ListBlobls()
  .OfType<CloudBlockBlobWrapper>()
  .ToList();
```

There are more then **1 million** blobs in our container, as the `ListBlobs()` has a limit up to 5000, is there a way to extend the limit *without using* `ListBlobsSegmented();`

Answer (score 1):

`ListBlobs()` method actually lists all blobs in a blob container.

`ListBlobsSegmented()` only fetches up to 5000 blobs in a single call and if there are more blobs, it returns a continuation token. However `ListBlobs()` method internally handles the continuation token and returns you a list of all blobs.